# KeyListener after Button Is Pressed

Tags: java, actionlistener, keylistener

I'm creating a little application that will add a tray icon if the caps lock button is pressed. I'm getting a error that I can't seem to fix.

Here is my code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){

        //removed for StackOverflow

    }

 }
```

I'm getting the "Illegal start of expression" Error on the keyPressed Listener
Now this is probably a super simple fix, I just don't know it.

Comment: You cannot declare a method within another method in Java

Comment: YO DAWG I put a method inside a method so you can call it while you are calling it. You can set a boolean to true when the button action is fired and inside the keyPressed method you can check for the boolean.

Comment: @Jonah you need to create a key listener to handle the key event (to update the tray icon), AND a separate listener for the button.  In fact, it sounds like you need to use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: As mentioned before you cant put a method inside another method. Other than that post all of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyListener` will only be activated if the component it is registered to is focusable AND has focus. If the UI has some other component (like a button or textfield) then it will not work.

I'm assuming that you want to know whenever the caps lock state changes, regardless of what might have focus in your program.  To this end you can register a `AWTListener` with the `Toolkit` and monitor ALL key traffic that is been processed by your application.

With this listener, you could monitor of the `KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK` key event and take appropriate action.

If you need to know the exact state of the caps lock key, you can use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)` to determine if it is on or off...

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestListener();
    }

    public TestListener() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel capsStateLabel;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            capsStateLabel = new JLabel();
            add(capsStateLabel);
            updateLabelState();
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                    if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {

                        KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent) event;
                        switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
                            case KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK:
                                switch (ke.getID()) {
                                    case KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED:
                                    case KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED:
                                        updateLabelState();
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }, KeyEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
        }

        protected void updateLabelState() {
            boolean capsState = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
            if (capsState) {
                capsStateLabel.setText("Caps is ON");
            } else {
                capsStateLabel.setText("Caps is OFF");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As some of the commenters have stated, use a `KeyListener` instead:

```
public class CtrlToIconListener implements KeyListener {

  private boolean displayed = false;

  // consumed
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

  // when the key is first pressed
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    // if the control key is pressed, handled it.
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK) {
      displayed = !displayed;
    }
  }

  // when the key is released
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    // do something clever
  }

}
```

Then you'd use this class as a listener for your jFrame (I assume that's what you're using)

more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: could add a `getState()` method to return it, or handle displaying everything directly in the `keyPressed()` method, but yeah it doesn't do much as private I guess...heh.

Comment: One could do a lot of things but in this particular case `displayed` is useless(and I didn't say you wore wrong).

Comment: oh! sorry if I came off as annoyed! definitely not the case.

Comment: `KeyListener` will only be activated if the component it is registered to is focusable AND has focus.  If the UI has some other component (like a button or textfield) then this will not work.

Comment: I guess in that case it would probably be better to use an `ActionListener` that's attached to the component, or just give focus to the component.